# How do I connect a container to an existing container on creation?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a new container and connect it to an existing container, but I can't seem to get it right...

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=app --network app-net -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo app
```

I'm trying to get the new container to talk to the mongo container that is already running on the 'app-net' network, but I can't seem to get it right... What am I doing wrong here?